# Octobercms : Using rtl language as part of the url

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

I'm trying out octombercms for a project. As shown in the attached screenshot, I'm trying to create a static page using "Rainlab.Pages" plugin.

Content language is going to be Hebrew (which is rtl). When I try to save it shows an error "Invalid url format, url should start with / and should contain Latin chars ... ". I get same error when I try to create a cms page instead.

**I understand this is because of the rtl language in the url. I'd like to know how I should approach to solve this issue.**

Most of the search results I get talk about multilingual content, but for this project I just need the **frontend content and parts of the urls to be in Hebrew** and backend UI to be in English.

[image]